# php 7 mb_ (multibyte) functions are ~60% slower than in 5.3 (windows only issue)

Tags: php, performance, php-7, php-7.1

My application makes extensive use of mb_ string functions and switching to php 7 resulted in an overall slower application. I tracked down the issues to the mb_ string functions. Here are the benchmark code and the results:

```
$time = microtime();
$time = explode(' ', $time);
$start = $time[1] + $time[0];
$startms = $time[0];
    for ($i=0; $i<100000; $i++) {
        $a = mb_strlen("fdsfdssdfoifjosdifjosdifjosdij:ά", "UTF-8");
    }
$time = microtime();
$time = explode(' ', $time);
$finish = $time[1] + $time[0];
$finishms = $time[0];
$total_time = round(($finish - $start), 4);
echo "mb_strlen: " . $total_time*1000 ." milliseconds<br/>";

$time = microtime();
$time = explode(' ', $time);
$start = $time[1] + $time[0];
$startms = $time[0];
    for ($i=0; $i<100000; $i++) {
        $a = mb_stripos("fdsfdssdfoifjosdifjosdifjosdij:ά", "α", 0, "UTF-8");
    }
$time = microtime();
$time = explode(' ', $time);
$finish = $time[1] + $time[0];
$finishms = $time[0];
$total_time = round(($finish - $start), 4);
echo "mb_stripos: " . $total_time*1000 ." milliseconds<br/>";


$time = microtime();
$time = explode(' ', $time);
$start = $time[1] + $time[0];
$startms = $time[0];
    for ($i=0; $i<100000; $i++) {
        $a = mb_substr("fdsfdssdfoifjosdifjosdifjosdij:ά", $i, 1, "UTF-8");
    }
$time = microtime();
$time = explode(' ', $time);
$finish = $time[1] + $time[0];
$finishms = $time[0];
$total_time = round(($finish - $start), 4);
echo "mb_substr: " . $total_time*1000 ." milliseconds<br/>";
```

The platform is Windows 7 64bit, IIS 7.5:

```
php 5.3.28
mb_strlen: 250 milliseconds
mb_stripos: 3078.1 milliseconds
mb_substr: 281.3 milliseconds

php 7.1.1
mb_strlen: 406.3 milliseconds
mb_stripos: 4796.9 milliseconds
mb_substr: 421.9 milliseconds
```

I don't know if my set up is wrong or something, but seems inconceivable that the multibyte functions should be slower. Any ideas as to why and what to do to solve this ? Thank you in advance.

Edit: as apokryfos' comment suggests, this may be a Windows only problem.

Comment: Sorry, I just don't see it http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/401f138baf7c4110f1370f8e597bba5610dd0a47

Comment: @apokryfos I don't know what OS runs the test link you provided, maybe it's an issue with the windows version of php

Comment: Just for readability: `microtime` takes a boolean argument that makes it return a float already - no need to `explode` etc. - Thinking about it: That might be the whole problem, what's `$time = explode(' ', $time); $start = $time[1] + $time[0];` supposed to represent? You're just adding the msec part of the current timestamp to the seconds part?

Comment: @ccKep it's not wrong, because microtime() returns "0.66539800 1499759652". anyhow that is not what causes it

Comment: I see, I was under the impression it returned `66539800 1499759652` in that case - my bad. Point regarding readability stands ;-)

Comment: @PaulCrovella if so, shouldn't have it changed for the better, like almost everything else ?

Comment: @PaulCrovella indeed you are right. However as apokryfos may have suggested through his link, what I describe doesn't seem to happen under Linux, which may imply a problem in the Windows implementation of the library

Comment: I can confirm that PHP 7.1 vs 5.6 on Windows performs slower. I'm getting around 400/4000/400 on 7.1 and 140/1500/140 on 5.6. Computer is a Dell 7470, and I ran several iterations in case there was a spike in results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can confirm that your result is reproducible on Windows 7.
After some experiments, I found a quick solution that IMO should not even have an effect.

As you can see from [mb_strlen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) function signature,
it will use internal encoding if you omit the encoding parameter.
This also applies to other functions that you use.

```
mixed mb_strlen ( string $str [, string $encoding = mb_internal_encoding() ] )
```

What I found odd is if you set internal encoding to UTF-8 by calling `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8")` and omit the encoding parameter,
the functions got faster.

PHP 5.5 result:

```
5.5.12

with encoding parameter:
- mb_strlen: 172 ms, result: 5
- mb_substr: 218 ms, result: う
- mb_strpos: 218 ms, result: 3
- mb_stripos: 1,669 ms, result: 3
- mb_strrpos: 234 ms, result: 3
- mb_strripos: 1,685 ms, result: 3

with internal encoding:
- mb_strlen: 47 ms, result: 5
- mb_substr: 78 ms, result: う
- mb_strpos: 62 ms, result: 3
- mb_stripos: 1,669 ms, result: 3
- mb_strrpos: 94 ms, result: 3
- mb_strripos: 1,669 ms, result: 3
```

PHP 7.0 result:

```
7.0.12

with encoding parameter:
- mb_strlen: 640 ms, result: 5
- mb_substr: 702 ms, result: う
- mb_strpos: 686 ms, result: 3
- mb_stripos: 7,067 ms, result: 3
- mb_strrpos: 749 ms, result: 3
- mb_strripos: 7,130 ms, result: 3

with internal encoding:
- mb_strlen: 31 ms, result: 5
- mb_substr: 31 ms, result: う
- mb_strpos: 47 ms, result: 3
- mb_stripos: 7,270 ms, result: 3
- mb_strrpos: 62 ms, result: 3
- mb_strripos: 7,116 ms, result: 3
```

Unfortunately, this quick solution isn't perfect as `mb_stripos()` and `mb_strripos()` don't seem to be affected.
They are still slow.

This is the code (shortened):

```
echo PHP_VERSION."\n";
echo "\nwith encoding parameter:\n";

$t = microtime(true)*1000;
for($i=0; $i<100000; $i++){
    $n = mb_strlen("あえいおう","UTF-8");
}
$t = microtime(true)*1000-$t;
echo "- mb_strlen: ".number_format($t)." ms, result: {$n}\n";

$t = microtime(true)*1000;
for($i=0; $i<100000; $i++){
    $n = mb_substr("あえいおう",-1,1,"UTF-8");
}
$t = microtime(true)*1000-$t;
echo "- mb_substr: ".number_format($t)." ms, result: {$n}\n";

//set internal encoding
//and omit encoding parameter

mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
echo "\nwith internal encoding:\n";

$t = microtime(true)*1000;
for($i=0; $i<100000; $i++){
    $n = mb_strlen("あえいおう");
}
$t = microtime(true)*1000-$t;
echo "- mb_strlen: ".number_format($t)." ms, result: {$n}\n";

$t = microtime(true)*1000;
for($i=0; $i<100000; $i++){
    $n = mb_substr("あえいおう",-1,1);
}
$t = microtime(true)*1000-$t;
echo "- mb_substr: ".number_format($t)." ms, result: {$n}\n";
```

Comment: Wow that's weird

Comment: someone please file a bug report, this gotta be a bug

Answer (score 4):

this sounds like a "performance regression" bug. should probably file a bugreport, so the php core devs can take a look at it, at bugs.php.net

meanwhile, i see that in your snippets you're exclusively using UTF-8. as long as you are exclusively using UTF-8, you might be able to speed it up using preg_, which only supports 1 kind of unicode characterset: `UTF-8`. here's my attempt:

```
function _mb_strlen(string $str, string $encoding = 'UTF-8'): int {
    assert ( $encoding === 'UTF-8' );
    preg_match ( '/.$/u', $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );
    return empty ( $matches ) ? 0 : ($matches [0] [1]) + 1;
}
function _mb_stripos(string $haystack, string $needle, int $offset = 0, string $encoding = 'UTF-8') {
    assert ( $encoding === 'UTF-8' );
    if ($offset !== 0) {
        throw new LogicException ( 'NOT IMPLEMENTED' );
    }
    preg_match ( '/' . preg_quote ( $needle ) . '/ui', $haystack, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );
    return empty ( $matches ) ? false : $matches [0] [1];
}
function _mb_substr(string $str, int $start, int $length = NULL, string $encoding = 'UTF-8'): string {
    assert ( $encoding === 'UTF-8' );
    if ($start < 0) {
        throw new LogicException ( 'NOT IMPLEMENTED' );
    } elseif ($start > 0) {
        $rex = '/.{' . $start . '}(.{0,';
    } else {
        $rex = '/(.{0,';
    }
    if ($length !== NULL) {
        $rex .= $length;
    }
    $rex .= '})/u';
    preg_match ( $rex, $str, $matches );
    // var_dump ( $rex, $matches );
    return empty ( $matches ) ? '' : $matches [1];
}
```

here's my benchmark results on 100,000 iterations on php 7.0 on debian 9 linux (kernel 4.9):

mb_strlen got slower, from about 60ms to 100 ms

mb_stripos got A LOT FASTER, from about 1400ms to 75ms

mb_substr got A LOT SLOWER, from about 47 ms to about 800 ms

- but i suggest you re-run these tests on windows, as you said you think it might be a windows-exclusive issue

also note, these functions are not feature complete, as you can see from the LogicException's they throw.

also note that due to a limitation in preg_ , i had to cap mb_substr at 65000 iterations in

```
for($i = 0; $i < 65000; $i ++) {
    $a = mb_substr ( "fdsfdssdfoifjosdifjosdifjosdij:ά", $i, 1, "UTF-8" );
}
```

because, if you ask preg to look for a string over 65,000 characters long, it will give an error...

also note that your benchmark code can be made a lot easier, all of this

```
$time = microtime();
$time = explode(' ', $time);
$start = $time[1] + $time[0];
$startms = $time[0];
    for ($i=0; $i<100000; $i++) {
        $a = mb_strlen("fdsfdssdfoifjosdifjosdifjosdij:ά", "UTF-8");
    }
$time = microtime();
$time = explode(' ', $time);
$finish = $time[1] + $time[0];
$finishms = $time[0];
$total_time = round(($finish - $start), 4);
echo "mb_strlen: " . $total_time*1000 ." milliseconds<br/>";
```

can simply be replaced with

```
$starttime=microtime(true);
    for ($i=0; $i<100000; $i++) {
        $a = mb_strlen("fdsfdssdfoifjosdifjosdifjosdij:ά", "UTF-8");
    }
$endtime=microtime(true);
echo "mb_strlen: " . number_format(($endtime-$starttime),3) ." seconds<br/>";
```

which outputs something like: `mb_strlen: 0.085 seconds`
(which means about 85 milliseconds)

or

```
echo "mb_strlen: " . number_format(($endtime - $starttime) * 1000),2) . " milliseconds<br/>";
```

(and i can take a wild guess that it has something to do with realloc() performance, in which linux stomps windows, but i got no proof)

Comment: thank you for your reply. just a comment for the time measuring optimization code: the reason it is as it is, and not optimized like you and others suggested, is that it breaks down for t>1sec (shows negatives values etc.)

Comment: Oh, to get around that you can use number_format() :) (I'm on a phone now so I won't fix it, but when I get back to the computer, I will )

Comment: @MIrrorMirror fixed it with number_format ^^ (and if you dont want the other formatting operations of number_format, simply give it 2 emptystring arguments at the end)